# What game is Jesse playing in the Breaking Bad episode, "Problem Dog"?

Tags: game-identification

In episode 7 of *Breaking Bad* season 4, "Problem Dog", you can see one of the main characters (Jesse Pinkman) playing a video game around 00:40:

[image: Screenshot of game]

It looks to me like a first person shooter. The enemies bald guys with a sickle, and some of them also wear scarves that cover the lower half of their head. I believe the setting is rather new, since I can see graffiti on the walls. The part of game shown is in wet underground rooms.

What is the name of this game he's playing?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The game that Jesse Pinkman is playing in the opening scene of *Breaking Bad* season 4, "Problem Dog" is [*RAGE*](http://www.rage.com), by [id software](http://www.idsoftware.com).

[image: RAGE game over]

[Source](https://www.stereogum.com/1762115/breaking-bad-s04e07-eyes-open-mouths-shut-jesse-forever/videogum/)

Comment: Though note that the game is an FPS, not a track-based shooter.  This scene of the game appears to have been specially-made for the show.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft, it is also possible they used a custom controller. Light guns have been developed for console shooters like this.

Comment: Note that the full game hadn't yet been released at the time the episode aired. And per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rage_(video_game)#Marketing_and_release): "id took mostly pre-existing game areas (the Well area), but worked with the production of the show to include allusions and references to Gale's murder to tie into Jesse's narrative within the game, such as Gale's name written on walls. From there, they provided a lot of pre-recorded game footage to AMC to work with. Though the show has Jesse playing *Rage* via a light gun, this was not part of the end development."